# Conversion of image to unsigned char*

Tags: android, c++, objective-c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on an app that is communicating with external SDK using NDK for processing on image data. Input type of SDK for image is unsigned char*. In iOS it is working fine and below is the Objective-C code that is used there.

```
unsigned char *dataImage     =   (unsigned char*) 
malloc(bytesPerRow*height);
CGColorSpaceRef colors  =   CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context    =   CGBitmapContextCreate(dataImage, width,height, BITSPERCOMPS, bytesPerRow, colors, 
(CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, width, height), imageRef);
```

This dataImage is passed to SDK and it return correct results. Now, I am trying to generate similar stream of image data in Android but SDK always returns false. Here are the steps that I performed for converting image to unsigned char* in Android,

1. Get bitmap/base64 (tried with both) image data
2. Get byte array form bitmap/base64
3. Pass byte array to C++
4. Convert byte array to unsigned char* in C++ (As unsigned char* not available in Android/Java I have to convert it in C++ portion)

Here is the code for conversion to unsigned char*

```
int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength (env,image);
unsigned char* buf = malloc(len);
(*env)->GetByteArrayRegion (env,image, 0, len, (jbyte *) buf);
```

This is start of unsigned char* dump in android

```
"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"
```

And this is unsigned char* generated in Objective C

```
A\^X
\M^?B\^Y\M^?B\^Y\M^?B\^Z\M^?B\^\
\M^?B\^\
\M^?C\^]\^N\M^?D\^]\^N\M^?E\^_\^P\M^?D\^^\^O\M^?A\^\
```

Comment: The first "dump" is clearly not the actual image content, but a PNG-file [or you got extremely "lucky" when dumping exactly that content, but I strongly suspect you are dumping a PNG file, not a bunch of pixel values] - this is similar to saying "My PDF file doesn't look like the text-string that I created it from".

Comment: Actually that what I am thinking. As in iOS conversion code you can see image is drawn/created in memory from original image data and then that image ia converted, so is there something like this in Android too? Where we only have image data. I thought that bitmap data is similar thing like it should not have file information just image data stream. It seams that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are quite familiar with android NDK, if not then take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html). I didn't test it but I would approach it like this:

1) Load the bitmap and get the byteArray from the outputStream:

```
Bitmap bmp; // your bitmap 
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
// Call native function defined below
passByteArrayToJni(byteArray);
```

2) Declare native function somewhere in your class

```
// Declare native function in NDK
public native passByteArrayToJni(byte[] byteArray);
```

3) In .cpp file:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_packageX_ClassY_passByteArrayToJni( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray byteArray);
{
    // Reads byte array to * cBytes
    jbyte * cBytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(byteArray, &isCopy);
    // Gets the size
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, byteArray);

    // Get region
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(len);
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion (env,cBytes, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));


    // Releases array when done with it.
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(byteArray, cBytes, JNI_ABORT);
}
}
```

Hope that will work  for you, please tell me if any problems.

Comment: I'm getting this error
 SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xdeadd00d))

on this line 
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion (env,cBytes, 0, len, (jbyte *)buf);